# jython unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, jython

May I know why this test fails even though the function actually throws the exception?

```
def testDateCreation(self):
   self.assertRaises(ValueError, datetime.date(2013, 2, 29))
```

Answer (score 2):

You either have to use [`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) as context manager (if running python 2.7):

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    datetime.date(2013, 2, 29)
```

or provide a function which [`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) can call:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, lambda: datetime.date(2013, 2, 29))
```

Otherwise, the exception is raised *before* `assertRaises` is called, and thus can't be handled.

Comment: Both methods work. Thank you so much, Dominic. You must be a python champ. I will upvote your answer once I have enough reputation.